# How to I redirect the link from the google calendar entries from my RSS feed to another web page?

Tags: html, url, redirect, iframe

I have an RSS feed powered by RSS Pump drawing stuff from my Google Calendar. Now it's doing this by using a bit of HTML with an 'iframe' in and I want to know how I can redirect all the links on the RSS news items to another web page, not to google calendar entries. Do I need to put some special code round it to redirect it? Here is the code:

```
<iframe src="http://s1.rsspump.com/rss.aspx?s=e0431bb0-cd2b-4f8f-ab47-619c3d841bab&amp;speed=1&amp;t=0&amp;d=0&amp;u=0&amp;p=1&amp;b=0&amp;ic=5&amp;font=Verdana&amp;fontsize=12px&amp;bgcolor=&amp;color=000000&amp;type=typewriter&amp;su=0&amp;sub=0&amp;sw=0" frameborder="0" width="100%" height="18" scrolling="no" allowtransparency="true"></iframe>
<noframes>
  <div style="background-color: none transparent;">
    <a href="http://news.rsspump.com/" title="Latest News">News</a>
  </div>
</noframes>
```

Answer (score 0):

The data is in an iframe, loaded from another domain and not under your control. You can't change where the links go (since it would otherwise be a horrific security risk).